# Linear operator T is one to one, Is the integral inequality $\|(f+Tf)h\|_{L^{1}}\leq C\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{1/2}\|Tf\|_{L^{2}}^{1/2}\|h\|_{L^{2}}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I changed the question to:

When I read paper concerning about PDE, I encounter an inequality which simple edition is $\|(f+Tf)h\|_{L^{1}}\leq C\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{1/2}\|Tf\|_{L^{2}}^{1/2}\|h\|_{L^{2}}$ in which $f,Tf,h$ are all in $L^{2}$ and T is a one-to-one linear operator from $L^{2}$ to $L^{2}$. Is it right, I don't know how to do it. Thanks!

Remark: From the comment I know that if T is zero oprator, the inequality is not right. **But if T is not the zero operator and f is not in the kernel of T, is this inequality right?**. Now I change the question again, that is T is injective and surjective. Is this inequality right? What I want to know is that does this inequality **hold for special T satisfying the above condition: one-to-one and linear**

Comment: Cannot be right in full generality, what if $T$ is the zero operator?

Comment: yeah, thank you for your comment! But if T is not the zero operator, does this inequality correct in general?

Comment: Saying $T$ is non -zero does not help in any way. Take $T=\frac 1   n I$ in the inequality and let $n \to \infty$ to get a  contradiction.

Comment: @geetha290krm
 Thank you very much. Maybe the paper what I read is not right.

Comment: @geetha290krm but when I fixe a special T, I can not judge whether the inequality is wrong. Your counterexample is for varying $T=\frac{1}{n}I$, but when I consider a special $T$, for example, $T=\frac{1}{10}I$, the inequality is right.

Comment: The inequality has to hold for **all** $T$, not just for one $T$.

Comment: @robjohn♦ why the inequality "has to" hold for all T?

Comment: That is what the inequality means: for *all* choices of $f$, $T$, and $h$ satisfying the given conditions, the statement is true.

Comment: I am so sorry that I can not express my question exactly. What I want to know is for a special T, is this inequality right?

Comment: Dear @Calvin Khor, $Tf=f$ is a so special case, but in that PDE paper, T is a just special operator satisfying some special condition, in that paper $Tf\neq f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I gather that you want the inequality to hold for a particular operator $T$ with the constant $C$ independent of  $f$ and $h$. You are also assuming that $T$ is a bounded operator which is bijective.
Under these conditions the inequality is true.

I will write $\|f\|_2$ for the norm in $L^{2}$.

By Holder's inequality the proof reduces to showing that

$$\|f+Tf\|_2^{2} \leq C^{2}\|f\|_2\|Tf\|_2$$

LHS $\leq (\|f\|_2+\|Tf\|_2)^{2}$ and $T$ is bounded, so we are left with an inequality of the type $\|f\|_2^{2}\leq D \|f\|_2\|Tf\|_2$. Such an inequality is immediate from Open Mappimng Theorem since $T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator.

Comment: Well thank you very much! I don't realize that open mapping theorem is so power